# ThreadPool - Does MaxThreads - AvailableThreads = CUrrent Number Of ThreadPool Threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

Will the following give me an accurate amount of ThreadPool threads running?

```
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out var availableWorkerThreads, out var availableCompletionPortThreads);
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var maxWorkerThreads, out var maxCompletionPortThreads);

var currentWorkerThreads = maxWorkerThreads - availableWorkerThreads;
var currentCompletionPortThreads = maxCompletionPortThreads - availableCompletionPortThreads;

Console.WriteLine("Current Worker Threads: " + currentWorkerThreads)
Console.WriteLine("Current Completion Port Threads: " + currentCompletionPortThreads)
```

Comment: Yes, of course, unless the documentation is mistaken. Read the doc for [ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads?view=netframework-4.7.1): "_Retrieves the difference between the maximum number of thread pool threads returned by the GetMaxThreads(Int32, Int32) method, and the number currently active._" In other words: `AvailableThreads = MaxThreads - currently active threads` Thus, through the power of m̶a̶g̶i̶c̶  math: `currently active threads = MaxThreads - AvailableThreads` (ThreadPool threads, of course)

Comment: Don't know how I missed that! I was certain I was on that page! Thanks for clarifying! Feel free to promote that to an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

It appears you can indeed use that to calculate the number of active thread pool threads.

At least on .NET Framework 4.6.1

## Test

I have wrote a noddy console app to test this, by scheduling a bunch of tasks, and seeing how many threads get created.

You can see that after 4 it waits for a little while before creating additional threads.

### Output

```
----  Start  ----  17:01:55.2583
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads: 2,047
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads: 2,047
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: 4
ThreadPool.CurrentThreads: 0


----  After Scheduling 1  ----  17:01:55.2793
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads: 2,046
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads: 2,047
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: 4
ThreadPool.CurrentThreads: 1


----  After Scheduling 50  ----  17:01:55.2803
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads: 2,043
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads: 2,047
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: 4
ThreadPool.CurrentThreads: 4


----  After Scheduling 500  ----  17:01:55.2813
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads: 2,043
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads: 2,047
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: 4
ThreadPool.CurrentThreads: 4


----  After Sleeping 30.00s  ----  17:02:25.3403
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads: 2,022
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads: 2,047
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: 4
ThreadPool.CurrentThreads: 25


----  After Sleeping 30.00s  ----  17:02:55.3453
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads: 2,004
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads: 2,047
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: 4
ThreadPool.CurrentThreads: 43

----  After Waiting for all 500  ----  17:03:25.3573
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads: 2,047
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads: 2,047
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: 4
ThreadPool.CurrentThreads: 0
```

### Code

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OutputThreadCount("Start");

        var millisecondsDelay = 5000;

        ScheduleTasks(1, millisecondsDelay);

        OutputThreadCount("After Scheduling 1");

        ScheduleTasks(50, millisecondsDelay);

        OutputThreadCount("After Scheduling 50");

        ScheduleTasks(500, millisecondsDelay);

        OutputThreadCount("After Scheduling 500");

        var all = Task.WhenAll(_tasks);

        while (!all.IsCompleted)
        {
            var millisecondsTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
            OutputThreadCount($"After Sleeping {millisecondsTimeout.TotalSeconds:N2}");
        }

        OutputThreadCount("After Waiting for all 500");


        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void ScheduleTasks(int taskCount, int millisecondsDelay)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(millisecondsDelay));

            _tasks.Add(task);
        }
    }

    private static void OutputThreadCount(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"----  {message}  ----  {DateTime.UtcNow:HH:mm:ss.ffff}");

        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out var availableWorkerThreads, out var availableCompletionPortThreads);
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var maxWorkerThreads, out var maxCompletionPortThreads);
        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out var minWorkerThreads, out var minCompletionPortThreads);

        Console.WriteLine($"ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads: {availableWorkerThreads:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine($"ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads: {maxWorkerThreads:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine($"ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: {minWorkerThreads:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine($"ThreadPool.CurrentThreads: {maxWorkerThreads - availableWorkerThreads:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```